# multiple assignments in one line for loop python

Tags: python, for-loop, multiple-assignment

I would like a one line way of assigning two variables to two different values in a for loop.

I have a list of list of values

```
list_values = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

I have tried to do this, and it works but is not pythony:

```
first = [i[0] for i in list_values]
second = [i[1] for i in list_values]
```

Which makes:

```
first = [1, 4]
second = [2, 5]
```

I *want* to write something like:

```
first, second = [i[0]; i[1] for i in list_values]
```

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`zip()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) instead:

```
first, second = zip(*list_values)[:2]
```

or the Python 3 equivalent:

```
from itertools import islice

first, second = islice(zip(*list_values), 2)
```

`zip()` pairs up elements from the input lists into a sequence of new tuples; you only need the first two, so you slice the result.

Answer (score 0):

`list_values = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]`

`first, second = [[i[0], i[1]] for i in list_values]`

Next time use something other than the "i", like "elem" etc.